# Paired sample t-test equivalent for intensive longitudinal assessments

Tags: multilevel-analysis, paired-data

I am a bit new to multilevel and mixed-effects modeling. I have a dataset, where I have sensor measurements throughout the day for 4 weeks on N participants. I have some prompts on their smartphones 60 - 70 times a day. All I want to do is to see if the sensor measurement before the prompt differs from the measurement after the prompt. I think paired sample t-test is a good option, but with high intensity of data, I don't think it meets all the assumptions of the test. Any suggestions or leads will be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to CV, RforResearch! This isn't an answer (and hence I make a comment), but when thinking longitudinally, there may be lots of ways to think about differences. See my answer to the question [Which stats tests to use? Bee flight activity quantified during an eclipse](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125498/which-stats-tests-to-use-bee-flight-activity-quantified-during-an-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I am going through. trying to understand the nuances.

Comment: @Alexis, I think the key difference is that I have multiple participants, with multiple data points within a day for 4 weeks.

Comment: And **what specific differences are you interested in?** (My point was *not* that I answered your question, but that you might find the advice to think about specific differences meaningful to *you* worthwhile. :)

Comment: Hey Alexis, I just want to check if the sensor measurement n seconds before the prompt is significantly different from the same measurement n sec after the prompt. Note that sensor is measuring all the time.