# compare the means of two cross sectional time series

Tags: time-series, panel-data, cross-section

I have bi-variate annual ($n=6$) time series data for each company $i$ (number of companies $k=5$):
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
X_{it}  \\
Y_{it}  
\end{bmatrix} ,\, i = 1,\dots, k,\, t = 1,\dots, n$$
Where $X_{it}$ and $Y_{it}$ are not independent ($X$ is actual profit and $Y$ is expected profit).

We want to test if there is a significant difference between $X$ and $Y$ with this data? What is the appropriate test?

I think it may use t-test or Wilcoxon test for each company and get $k$ decisions (one for each company), but I don't know how can we damage all this results together.

I thought also that if we combined the data of all companies together, it might be possible to compare common means (actual and expected).

Comment: Difference between $X_{t}$ and $Y_{t}$ *when?* For example, if $X_{t} = Y_{t}$ except at a single point in time, would that be "difference" for you? How large would such a difference need to be? What is the *specific question* you want answered? (There is no "general" difference, only specifics, see [my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125538/44269).)

Comment: many thanks @Alexis. It is helpful.